# Associate tables from different database cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have two database with name default and default_history. And tables with name users and wafer_detail_history under default database and order_history under default_history database. want to associate Users table with OrderHistory table.

OrderHistoryTable :-

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('order_history');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('WaferDetailHistory', [
        'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

}
```

i used this.

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default_history');
$this->OrderHistory = TableRegistry::get('OrderHistory');
$this->OrderHistory->setConnection($connection);
$id = 37;
$order_history = $this->OrderHistory->get($id, ['contain' => ['Users']]);
```

but not able to succeed. getting this error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'default_history.users'
>   doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago,

You must had 'strategy' => 'select' in your BelongTo to join with the other database

```
 $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'strategy' => 'select'
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the OrderHistoryTable.php File:

```
$this->setTable('default_history.order_history');
```